# Is there any way to generate the id of a document in firebase as a field? Using Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I use angular fire, as any new document i create generates also an id in firebase database, 
can i somehow manage to make this id as a field?

For example i save the title and an array with tags, but i also need to be saved a field named id that will contain document id.

```
public createSavedDoc( title: string, tags: string[] ): void {

const savedFields = {
  title: title,
  tags: tags
}

this.db.collection('saved').add(savedFields);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to keep the id of the document as a field in the data.

```
public createSavedDoc( title: string, tags: string[] ): void {

 var documentKey = this.db.database.ref().child('saved').push().key;
      this.db.database.ref('saved/'+documentKey).set({
        documentId:documentKey,
        title:title,
        tags:tags
      }); 
}
```